# Tabulator : date format is not coming as expected in the excel formula bar

Tags: jquery, momentjs, tabulator

I am downloading tabulator data into an excel file. The date format is coming as expected in the UI as well as in the excel file as shown below:

On HTML :

[image]

In Excel column :

[image]

In Excel Formula Bar :

[image]

My code is as follows.

Inside columns :

```
{field: 'periodEnd', title: 'PeriodEnd', headerSort: false, formatter: "datetime", formatterParams:{outputFormat: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'}, resizable: false, width: 200}
```

Inside downloadDataFormatter:

```
downloadDataFormatter:function(data){
                    data.data.forEach(function(row){
                        row.periodEnd = formatDateForDownload(row.periodEnd);
                    });
                    return data;
                  }
```

But what I want in the formula bar in excel upon clicking on the column is like below format:

[image]

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because downloaded files include the raw unformatted data. The reason for this is a lot of the formatters *(star formatter or progress bar)* add visual elements that would not work in most download formats.

You would need to use an accessor, in this case the `accessorDownload` option in the column definition to transform the data and format it as you need.

As a quick example we could make an accessor that prepended the string "Mr " to the front of every name in a file that was being downloaded. We would start by defining the accessor function:

```js
function mrAccessor paramLookup(value, data, type, component, row){
    return "Mr " + value;
}
```

Then we assign it in that columns definition:

```js
{title:"Name", field:"name", accessorDownload:mrAccessor },
```

Full details on accessors can be found in the [Accessor Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/mutators#accessors)

If you wanted a starting point for how to do the data transform, you could have a look at the source code for the datetime formatter [Here](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/master/src/js/modules/Format/defaults/formatters/datetime.js)